Cross-site Scripting (XSS) in the src property
Currently in my code I have an image snippet where I pass a src with native image import within my project folder. Previously I was directly passing the image import nomenclature within the src. To try to mitigate the vulnerability, I created a control function for the src input, but even so the vulnerability continues to be pointed out in my pentests.
How can I solve this?
my import exemple:
import corporativos from "../../img/Corporativo.svg";
my icons object:
const icons = {
    Mobilidade: mobilidades,
    Eventos: eventoss,
    Passagem: passagem,
    Locação: locacao,
    Hospedagem: hospedagem,
    Corporativo: corporativos,
    Empty: empty,
    Aéreo: passagem,
  };

my function geticons validate:
const getIconSrc = (name) => {
    return icons[name] || null;
  };

my img tag:
 <img
   src={getIconSrc("Empty")}
   alt="Nenhum ModeloVCN Cadastrado!"
 />

